# Azure Parse incoming hex data from IoT Hub

Tags: azure, azure-iot-hub

I have a device which sends data in the form of Hexadecimal value based on an algorithm to IoT Hub. I want to parse that data into a json string to store it in Cosmos DB. Is there any way to achieve this?

Comment: you can use the Azure Stream Analytics job with user-defined function, see https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/stream-analytics/stream-analytics-javascript-user-defined-functions and output to the Cosmos DB

Answer (score 1):

I would like to add to Roman's comment on your question, he's right to offer [this link](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/stream-analytics/stream-analytics-javascript-user-defined-functions#call-a-javascript-user-defined-function-in-a-query) to Stream Analytics. It will get the job done. Depending on how many devices you have and how often you are receiving telemetry, you might want to consider using Azure Functions instead. See [this sample](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/samples/azure-samples/functions-js-iot-hub-processing/processing-data-from-iot-hub-with-azure-functions/) on how to integrate Azure Functions between IoT Hub and CosmosDB.

The reason I offer this extra solution is that a Stream Analytics Job will cost you a fixed price per hour per streaming unit, while a Function is paid by consumption. Because the conversion from hexadecimal is a fairly small Function, you might even [use it for free](https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/pricing/details/functions/) whereas a Stream Analytics Job in West Europe will cost at least 74 Euros.